# Script to fill a value automatically in the webpage input box

Tags: javascript, html, automation, bookmarklet, tampermonkey

My job is to order diagnostic tests for patients and I need to write 6-7 characters value for each diagnostic test. I have 24 different values and I need to fill it many thousands of times. I am thinking to create 24 different scripts with Tampermonkey to speed up my job by clicking on the script box.
So the thing is that I need to fill this
[box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1HKU.png). Here are the input id and everything of that box in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGhOa.png). Then I type the value manually, I get popup list which updates every time I type one character (same principle as google or youtube search box), here is the [popup list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQzPV.png) after I type a value and if I want that diagnostic test, I need to click on it from the popup list, I cannot just simply click enter. So this is the code I have to fill the box by a value:

`document.body.appendChild(element)
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").value = '15002 '
    })`

The script fills the value, but the popup list doesn't appear and I need to click on the box, delete one character and write it again to get a list and then to choose a diagnostic test from it. Still, time-consuming.

I wonder, is it possible to make a script to add automatically a diagnostic test from the list like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCdur.png)? If no, is it somehow possible to make that popup list would appear and I won't need to click on the box, delete one character and write it again? At least, could I make that the box is clicked after a value has been filled? I tried this code but doesn't work: `document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").click()`

Please help me to make it as automatic as possible, which would save me hundreds of hours in the long-term.

Comment: You only have a click handler, which means you will have to click on it. If you want the list to simply appear when the user clicks or tabs to it, then you'd have to use "focus". As far as auto-filling it, whenever that list emits a change (every time you enter characters in the text field and the list updates), you could grab the first item in the list and assign that value to the text box. This might not be ideal, as the user may want the second or third item etc, but it would auto-update the textbox.

Comment: click appears now but a list doesn't. Still need to click space, so it appears

Comment: I'd say at this point, you have to post a working sample of your code. That way it's possible to see exactly what's going on (the pictures are semi-useful but code would be better). It doesn't have to be your production code, just create a simple "base case" of what you're trying to accomplish so we can run it (from a debug perspective) and see what's going on. If you do that I'm sure you'll get a fix quickly enough.

Comment: @Tim-Consolazio
`(function() {
    document.body.appendChild(element)
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").value = '15002'
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").focus()
     })
})();`

It fills and clicks, but the list doesn't come out. Here is the script for youtube search box, it's the same, the list doesn't appear. 
        `document.querySelector("input#search").value = 'usa'
        document.querySelector("input#search").focus()`

Comment: @TimConsolazio if this could be solved would be perfect. It should fill the box, and after a list popup it should pick the first and the only one option (as value is unique for just one diagnostic test), do you have a discord? we could discuss it there.

Comment: Really what we need is a plunkr or some such, or at least an HTML page with the s scripts, something that shows us the current *working* state. Code fragments in a comment means we just have to try and create a working sample on our own.

Comment: Agree with @TimConsolazio that speculating about a solution without the page content may prove frustrating. With that said, I've had a similar experience trying to create a [bookmarklet](https://github.com/mossrich/Bookmarklets/blob/master/WebexAutologin.js) that fills a form in a Vue.js page.  If your page is written with Vue.js you may have to dispatch the 'input' [event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) after filling the form. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1 - As for the second part of the question. Picture 4.

It is pretty simple to make an auto-fill for the dropping parametres, we just might need the html-code of the elements.

For example,

- `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();` clicks the first input checkbox from the first input
- `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex = 1;` selects the second value from the first select
- `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();`clicks the first button

To make it more precise you might use class at first, at then tag:
`document.getElementsByClassName('testClassDependingOnExistingClasses')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();` for example.

Anything you do manually on a page like that can be done automatically with JS.

2 - As for the first part of the question. Picture 2.
Here is the part of the answer.
[How to trigger arrow down press in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653401/how-to-trigger-arrow-down-press-in-js/64583122#64583122)

Maybe this code might help, but not enough information, since no data on html-code of the dropped elements.

`document.getElementById('generic_test_order_search').clildren[0].click();`