# How to trigger arrow down press in js?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have this code that fills and focuses but I need to add an arrow down event as it will trigger list popup like pictured below. Can anyone help me with the line?

```
document.body.appendChild(element)

    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").value = '16048'
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").focus()

     })


})();
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I suppose you need to send a `keydown`, then a `keyup` [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) with right properties to that element. Arrow keys may be [slightly tricky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [KeyboardEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Use the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) or [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event - depending on which one suits you better, and look up the keycode (the arrow down keycode is 40). When the key is pressed, the event will trigger. You can use the website to check which keycode is linked to which key on the keyboard by clicking [here](https://keycode.info/).

I got the code below from the MDN web docs.

```
eventTarget.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 229) {
    return;
  }
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Did this 
`element.addEventListener('click', function(){

        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").value = '16048'
        document.querySelector("input#generic_test_order_search.ui-autocomplete-input").focus()
        document.eventTarget.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 40) {
    return;
  }
  // do something
});


     })


})();`

but still, it doesn't trigger an arrow down event.

Comment: Based on the example that you've used the first time, it seems that you're already focused on the first item that is suggested (because of the focus()). I'd recommend adding some other suggested items. If it doesn't work after that, you can start implementing the example that I showed.

Comment: Try to use the code you posted here earlier when you were asking your question, and try adding another suggestion that is being shown when the user clicks in the input box (in the screenshot you used 15002).
Then see if you can select an item using the arrow keys, without using the code I suggested. It might be implemented by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information. It might be better to provide full HTML...

(A bit connected question: [Script to fill a value automatically in the webpage input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614205/script-to-fill-a-value-automatically-in-the-webpage-input-box))

1 - The goal here is to get `class` of the suggestion dropmenu. And find `children` inside, and maybe another `children` inside, and then trigger `click()` on it.

Since it is pretty hard to guess the class names and the structure, here is a pretty much **equal example** of how to click on drop-down suggestion.

a) Here is Wikipedia. Open the link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange

b) Save the following code as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions')[0].children[0].children[1].click();
})();
```

c) Then write three letters `goo` to the search in Wikipedia.

d) And finally trigger the bookmarklet. Then it will open up the second suggested link: `children[1]`. This is how it may work. You might try like this with your HTML on your own.

2 - There is a chance that making a **bookmarklet** might be a slightly better than appending an event listener, since all you need is to insert values.

Another option is **Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey** to trigger things even more automatically (in fact, this option is pretty much the same as a bookmarklet, and the code structure is absolutely the same and fully compatible).